# Daf-Yomi for its contents or for the concept?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags, tag-wiki

The tag [daf-yomi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daf-yomi) has been used most of the time for questions about the concept. For example:

[Looking for daf yomi app recommendations](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18279/looking-for-daf-yomi-app-recommendations)

[Preparing to learn daf yomi Yerushalmi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17174/preparing-to-learn-daf-yomi-yerushalmi)

[Daf Yomi Scheduling for Shabbos, Yom Tov, and Sundays](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18257/daf-yomi-scheduling-for-shabbos-yom-tov-and-sundays)

On the other hand, it was also used for a question on the actual daf:

[Kohanim on first shift can't say Shema'?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18285/kohanim-on-first-shift-cant-say-shema)

---

Which is the intended purpose of the tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about intended, but I support your first category. The latter category is no better at telling you what's in the question than the tag [talmud-gemara](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talmud-gemara).

Comment: I agree, and I think that the intent (which is the useful one) is pretty clear from all but one of the usages. I retagged the one that apparently made the other assumption to not include the tag and proposed a tag wiki.

Comment: @IsaacMoses And I have approved it.

Comment: Boo............

Comment: @SethJ You are invited to post a competing answer if you disagre.

Comment: What about for questions asked about the daf of the day? Or about the system of daf yomi. Aren't there Devarim tags and Parashat Hashavua tags, both, as well?

Comment: @AdamMosheh , questions about the content of any daf should be tagged with [tag:talmud-gemara] and/or the relevant tractate tag. Questions about the Daf Yomi system should be tagged [tag:daf-yomi].